# "wordpress" file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, file-get-contents

I have a WordPress plugin that I created and it has stopped working because of a certificate error.

```
file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in
```

I contacted the inmotionhosting and they said the certificate was fine. The code in question is this:

```
$op = file_get_contents(plugins_url( '../PRTHSEL_Visualizer.html' , __FILE__ ));
```

It was suggested that I use an https request to get the file. I have searched but cannot find and answer on how to get a file contents within a WordPress plugin via https.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the file_get_contents() was given a url for a local file. Byt changing the path to a local it now works under PHP7. PHP 5 never verified the SSL by default but PHP7 does.

Comment: Man this issue cost me so much time, I wish I'd seen this earlier.